# Safecracker return param with created entry id

Tags: safecracker

I have a safecracker form where I need the user to create a new entry. When the form is submitted I want the return address to include the newly created entry id, but I can't figure out how via the documentation.

I have tried:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="submissions" return="submission-complete/ENTRY_ID" include_jquery="no" safecracker_head="no"}
```

And:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="submissions" return="submission-complete/{entry_id}" include_jquery="no" safecracker_head="no"}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

```
    $('form#publishForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
window.location.href = "/submission-complete/"+data.entry_id;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You first approach would work as ENTRY_ID and URL_TITLE constants can be used. So Safecraker would redirect to page yoursiteurl.com/submission-complete/xxx. If not could you clarify more this question.

Comment: Hi @BhashkarYadav. I have suddenly realised that this might be because I am redirecting with ajax. On page load I am finding the return hidden field, taking the address and then in the 'complete' call redirecting to it.

Comment: see my edit in your code. The data should be passed within complete function like complete: function(data) . try it. it would help. Also can you see the error console in case of JavaScript error.

Comment: @BhashkarYadav No errors in error console, but the entry id is returning as 'undefined'.

Comment: Can you alert data like: alert (data); and share what JSON you are getting. if its alerting undefined use my updated code. Seems complete function return an object....

Comment: just edited ... see now...

Comment: The new code works (with data in the function). Before it was outputting object Object... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned within you comment that you are submitting the Safecraker form with AJAX. The Ajax submission returns JSON data which have entry id also. So you can redirect with JavaScript with success function like:

```
window.location = "/submission-complete/"+data.entry_id;
```

Take a reference from here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/examples.html#ajax-driven-entry-form

Comment: Ah thanks. Not sure why, but now its not redirecting at all. Can you take a look at my code. I have added it to the question body.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Its now returning 'undefined' for the entry id though... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can since the entry ID won't be created until AFTER the form is submitted.

What you might be able to do is return to the *latest* entry from the logged in user, will should be the entry they just submitted via Safecracker.